# How to join on a list of values with Hibernate/HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I need to join a table on a list of values constructed by code.

This is the MySql request I'm trying to translate in HQL (Hibernate 4.1.8):

```
SELECT D.date, COUNT(*)
FROM Employee E, (SELECT '2013-01-31' AS date
    UNION ALL SELECT '2013-02-28'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2013-03-31'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2013-04-30'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2013-05-31'
    ...
) D
WHERE E.departure_date > D.date AND E.arrival_date <= D.date
GROUP BY D.date;
```

This returns somethings like:

```
date        | count(*)
----------------------
2013-02-28  | 42
2013-03-31  | 45
2013-04-30  | 45
2013-05-31  | 44
```

Hibernate does not support `UNION`.
How to do this in HQL, with one request ?

Thanks.

Comment: if hibernate doesn't implement in HQL a specific SQL instruction the only way to solve the problem is to use the SQLQuery object.

Comment: @Luca Yes, that's what I do for now. But I loose the interest of HQL abstraction.